# installing dashboard on Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dashboard, kubectl

world.
Trying to install the dashboard in Kubernetes with command:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0-beta4/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
```

The reply looks like this:

```
Failed to pull image "kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.0.0-beta4": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error pulling image configuration: Get https://production.cloudflare.docker.com/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/68/6802d83967b995c2c2499645ede60aa234727afc06079e635285f54c82acbceb/data?verify=1568998309-bQcnrEV6vQpN4irzUtO2FEIv%2FkE%3D: dial tcp: lookup production.cloudflare.docker.com on 192.168.73.1:53: read udp 192.168.73.91:35778->192.168.73.1:53: i/o timeout
```

And a simple ping command said:

```
ping: unknown host https://production.cloudflare.docker.com
```

After that I watched the domain from downforeveryoneorjustme service and it told me that the server is down.

```
It's not just you! production.cloudflare.docker.com is down.
```

Googling the problem showed that I need to configure the docker proxy, but I have no proxy in my setup..

```
https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/#configure-the-docker-client
```

Any thoughts? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check first [Cloudflare status](https://www.cloudflarestatus.com/):

There was multiple "DNS delays" and "Cloudflare API service issues" in the past few hours, which might have an effect on your installation.